# Unable to escape dollar sign in ruby_block chef resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, ruby-block

I'm writing a chef recipe wherein an sql command is run.

```
ruby_block 'SQL command' do
  block do
    report = open(ReportFile,'a')
    command = %Q( ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@#{dbHost2} 'su - #{oraSidUser} -c "#{oracleHome}/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF
SELECT FLASHBACK_ON FROM V$DATABASE;
EOF"' )
    commandObj = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(command, :timeout => 60)
    commandObj.run_command()
    report.puts("Command:#{command}\nOutput:#{commandObj.stdout}\nError:#{commandObj.stderr}\nExit code:#{commandObj.exitstatus}")
  end
end
```

But when I check the log, it does not run the SQL command. It runs,

```
SQL> SELECT FLASHBACK_ON FROM V
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Seems it is trying to put the value of $DATABASE. I've tried using backslash to escape $. I've used double dollar sign. I've tried putting the SQL in a variable but it still does not run the correct SQL. Is there a different way to escape the dollar sign?

Edit:
With double backslash or triple backslash it fails with,

```
Error:DATABASE: Undefined variable.
```

Comment: Did you try double-escaping? like `V\\$DATABASE`?

Comment: Yes. It gave "undefined variable".

Answer (score 0):

since the `command` is a bash command, you need to escape the `$` sign, which is being evaluated in the shell as a variable.

append double backslash before the `$`, that is `\\$`

Comment: With double slash it gave "undefined variable"

Comment: @Ivan: do you have `DATABASE` environment variable defined?

Comment: I checked. It is not set. I ended up echoing the sql commands to a file and running the .sql